# Document Viewer - Change page from "Fading" into "direct"

Tags: pdf

I use `Document Viewer` for `PDF` and there is a little thing annoying: when changing pages into presentation mode, pages are changing by `Fading in` / `Fading out`(it takes a lot of time and it's disturbing for long pdfs)

Is there any way I can change the settings to `No animation` ?

Answer (score 0):

In **Okular** (Document Viewer in KDE), go to `Settings` > `Configure Okular` > `Presentation`: uncheck `Enable transitions` or set the `Default transition` to `Replace`.

There's probably a similar preference in **Evince**, the Document Viewer in Gnome/Unity if you're using that.